# Perform Action after the Binding Is Complete

Tags: sapui5

I wrote this part to bind OData information with a select controller:

```
var countrItems = new sap.ui.core.ListItem();
countrItems.bindProperty("key", "Land1");
countrItems.bindProperty("text", "Landx");
var CountrSelect = this.byId("CountrySelect");
CountrSelect.setModel(oModelTriptab);
CountrSelect.bindItems("/Countries", countrItems);
```

I would like to perform an action after the binding is complete (I want to select some default value that can change dynamically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the model's `requestCompleted` event handler to perform any actions that should happen right after your model data is updated.

The binding itself should be rather static (i.e. it will not change) so you'r only interested in when the data is changed

---

**edit** here's an example implemantation:

```
var that = this;
oModelTriptab.attachRequestCompleted(function(oEvent){
    var oSelect = that.byId("CountrySelect");
    oSelect.setSelectedKey("whatever");
});
```

See https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Model.html#attachRequestCompleted for more info

Comment: This is not a safe solution. I used this and it may happen the request completed while the items are not rendered yet!

Comment: It is a perfectly safe solution. I think you confuse the actual request being completed on the *model* (which is what OP is after) vs the *rendering* being completed (which is something entirely different and not related to the model). EDIT: having said that, this answer is more than 5 years old and the one below by Boghyon iswhat I prefer too

Comment: I mean using `dataReceived` is a better event to handle this situation. It may happen that the `RequestCompleted` happen and after that `DataReceived` happen.

Comment: Yes, absolutely agree, `dataReceived` on the binding should be the prefered solution

Answer (score 22):

Attach handlers to **events provided by [Binding](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.Binding/events)**:

```xml
<Select items="{
  path: '/Countries',
  events: {
    dataRequested: '.onCountriesRequested',
    dataReceived: '.onCountriesReceived',
    change: '.onCountriesChange'
  }
}">
```

Those events can be applied, not only to *ListBindings*, but to all bindings. **Note:** *PropertyBindings* do **not** trigger any requests, so no `dataRequested` or `dataReceived` for them.

> I would like to perform an action after the binding is complete.

In that case, you can attach a handler either to [`change`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.Binding/events/change) or [`dataReceived`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.Binding/events/dataReceived) event to be notified about the "complete" binding. You can discern whether the data request failed or not in the `dataReceived` handler: according to the API reference, the `data` parameter of the `dataReceived` event will be `undefined` if the request fails.

```js
onCountriesReceived: function(event) { // dataReceived
  const data = event.getParameter("data");
  if (data) { // request succeeded
    // ...
  }
},
```

Compared to attaching a handler to `requestCompleted`, the above approach is descriptive and binding specific.

---

### List, m.Table, m.Tree, ...

Alternatively, UI5 offers the event [`updateFinished`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.ListBase/events/updateFinished) for Controls derived from `sap.m.ListBase`. It's similar to the `change` event, but provides more information such as an additional `"Growing"` *reason*, *actual*, and *total* count of the entries.

```xml
<List
  updateFinished=".onCountriesUpdateFinished"
  items="..."
>
```

```js
onCountriesUpdateFinished: function(event) {
  const reasonForUpdate = event.getParameter("reason"); // "Refresh", "Growing", "Filter", "Sort", "Context", ...
  const currentlyLoadedNumberOfCountries = event.getParameter("actual");
  const totalNumberOfCountries = event.getParamter("total") // Value of $count
  // ...
}
```