# SAPUI5 Execute Code After Page has Fully Rendered

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am injecting a Javascript-File via a Chrome-Extension on a webpage that uses SAPUI5. 
I want to get the model in the binding context of some UI5-Input elements and in order to do so, I need to get to the inputs via `document.getElementsByTagName`. (or is there another way?)

This only works if they are already rendered. Unfortunately the ready or load events fire too early, when not everything is rendered yet.

Is there a way for me to know when the inputs have rendered?

Edit: I do not have access to the source code of the page, everything I do has to be in the injected script.

Comment: Is this a UI5 element? You haven't provided any code. if an `id` is set, you can get the binding context using `byId()` function.

Comment: It is a UI5-Element. I don't know the IDs of the inputs, I just know their type. But even if I did, byId() wouldn't work here, if the element is not yet rendered in the DOM-Tree or UI5-Tree, correct?

Comment: Another approach: 
1. Wait for model binding to complete. Check here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770332/perform-action-after-the-binding-is-complete
2. Is there a way for you to attach a custom class to UI5 input elements created ? If so, then use, `$(.customClass)[0].control()`. This is return a UI5 element. From there you can fetch its binding Context.

The problem is very interesting. Wish there was more you could share with us. May be a dummy code online for us to play with ?

Comment: My problem is I don't have the model stored somewhere in a variable, I have to somehow get it from the page. What I described in my question is an idea on how get to the point where I have the model stored in a variable in my script.

Comment: Do you have access to the global `sap` object from the target page? E.g. can you perform `sap.ui.getCore()`?

Comment: Yes, I can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did it like this:

I already had event listeners attached to click and key events. Every time the handler is called, I check if `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` returns the inputs I need.

If yes e. g. the rendering of the inputs is complete, I set a boolean that the page is loaded completely and execute my code.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure everything is renedered before firing your events, sapui5 has the function [onAfterRendering](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Control/methods/onAfterRendering).

All logic written in that function will only be executed **after** the control is rendered.

When a rerender of the control is rendered, the onAfterRendering is triggered again.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have access to the source code of the page, everything I do has to be inside the injected script. This function needs to be called on a control right? My problem is that I can't get the control as an object until it is rendered and I can get it via byId(). Is there any way I could get to the control before it is rendered?

Comment: Not true, `onAfterRendering` does not guarantee at all that

Comment: @bora89 what doesn't onAfterRendering guarantee? The official docu states 'Function is called when the rendering of the control is completed.'

Comment: @KristoffDT well try it out yourself, the key here is what they consider "render"

Comment: @bora89 please feel free to elaborate, I'm not entirely sure on what you are trying to say. Based on the question above & the official docu that I've linked, my answer feels eniterly correct. The important thing is to use the onAfterRendering on control-level.

kr