# Is there updateFinished when using sap.ui.table

Tags: sapui5

I need to replace sap.m.table to sap.ui.table. I realized the table contain "updateFinished" method.
If using sap.ui.table, what should i use? Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perform Action after the Binding Is Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770332/perform-action-after-the-binding-is-complete)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48443967/5846045

Answer (score 3):

For m.Table the event "updateFinished" is fired after the binding is updated and processed. For ui.table.Table the closest event would be "rowsUpdated":

> This event is fired after the table rows have been updated due to
> rendering, a model update, or a user interaction, for example.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.86.0/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table%23events/rowsUpdated

So this would be also triggered on eg scrolling the table, so you have adapt your code to handle only certain events.

Comment: sadly only since 1.86,... anyone found a solution that works in prior versions? the events of the binding dont work, because the rows change after those are triggered

Answer (score 2):

`rowsUpdated` is only available in 1.86 and newer versions.

If you are not using the latest version I would suggest the following approach:

Your binding also triggers events which can be handled in your controller.

```xml
<table:Table rows="{
        path: '/TableRowSet',
        events: {
            dataRequested: '.onDataRequested',
            dataReceived: '.onDataReceived',
            change: '.onChange'
        }
    }" />
```

These events are documented [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.Binding#events/Summary).